# Free PDF merging / compilation software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, merge, pdfcreator

I have 48 large files (created in Photoshop CS2 and saved as PDF) at around 94MB each that I need to merge and compresses and still have high quality for printing. What free or cheap software is available for Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simple PDF Merger](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/Simple-PDF-Merger.shtml) simple, convenient and free

Comment: as for "free, simple and convenient", have a look at FaxTool :) http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/FaxTool-Download-133262.html

Comment: but i really think, these images/PDFs require some serious processing/resizing prior to merging them.